# How do you get iPython to run on Console2?

Tags: python, ipython, console2

How do you really get iPython to run on Console2?  The instructions on the iPython site are not correct: http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/IpythonOnConsole.  (it says the Shell needs to be set to: cmd.exe /k "ipython")  I verified that python.exe is in my Path, etc. and I still get errors when I open an iPython tab saying ipython is not recognized.

Comment: And is ipython also on your path?

Comment: Provide more information: What command did you use to run it, what error message did you get, etc.

Comment: I provided all the info in the question: I get the error when I open the iPython tab in console2 and the error is that ipython is not recognized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out:  the Shell in the tab settings actually needs to be set to this:

```
cmd.exe /k "<my python path>\Scripts\ipython.py -p sh"
```

Where "< my python path >" is the dir of your python installation, such as "C:\Python26".

I added a page to the new [wiki](http://wiki.ipython.org/index.php?title=Cookbook/Using_IPython_with_Console2) and added a link to it in the cookbook.

Comment: We actually have a new wiki - http://wiki.ipython.org/ - if you want to put it there.

Comment: I added a page to the new [wiki](http://wiki.ipython.org/index.php?title=Cookbook/Using_IPython_with_Console2) and added a link to it in the cookbook.

Comment: I have windows XP and the following does not work. There is no "ipython.py" in my directory. There is a "ipython.exe" and if I use that the -p flag doesnt work. 

Shell: cmd.exe /k "< my python path >\Scripts\ipython.py -p sh"